# How can I get an array from an If statement?

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I'm trying to detect conditions of a string length within input fields. I need to know which condition(s) is met from the if statement and then put that/those in an array to display. Here's my code:

```
                if(strlen($post['first_name']) > 25
                    || strlen($post['last_name']) > 25
                    || strlen($post['email']) > 40
                    || strlen($post['phone']) > 15
                ){
                  $lengthTooLong = array();  
                  //do this
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use foreach.

```php
// define which keys of $post you want to check
// array value defines max length of value from $post[$key]
$keyToMaxLength = array(
    'first_name' => 25,
    'last_name' => 25,
    'email' => 40,
    'phone' => 15,
);
$lengthTooLong = array();
foreach($keyToMaxLength as $key => $maxLength) {    
    if(strlen($post[$key]) > $maxLength) {
        $lengthTooLong[] = $key; // or $post[$key]
    }
}
echo var_export($lengthTooLong, true);
```

[Working example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/547bcbff326bd53694b5977c00486164b347ac6d)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```php
$lengthTooLong = array();
if (strlen($post['first_name'])>25)) $lengthTooLong['first_name'] = $post['first_name'];
if (strlen($post['last_name'])>25)) $lengthTooLong['last_name'] = $post['last_name'];
/* etcetera */
if (count($lengthTooLong) == 0) unset $lengthTooLong;
```

That gets rid of your array when it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can try doing this

```
$lengthTooLong=array();
if(strlen($post['first_name']) > 25){
array_push($lengthTooLong, "first_name");
}
if(strlen($post['last_name']) > 25){
array_push($lengthTooLong, "last_name");
}
if(strlen($post['email']) > 40){
array_push($lengthTooLong, "email");
}
if(strlen($post['phone']) > 15){
array_push($lengthTooLong, "phone");
}
if(count($lengthTooLong>0){
   //do this
}
```